# Process NUnit result.xml and show it in Team City Web GUI

Tags: command-line, nunit, teamcity

I remember doing this in an older version of Team City in which the NUnit Runner failed, so I tried running NUnit using the Command Line Runner instead.

I think there was an option in the Command Line Runner settings which let you specify the kind of output file: NUnit result.xml was one of them. Doing this, you could see the test result breakdown in the Web GUI, just like when the NUnit Runner worked.

But I don't see this in the latest Team City (6.5.5). Can it still be done?

PS: Before anyone asks, I can't use Team City's NUnit Runner because NUnit has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/602761) which will be fixed in the soon to come 2.6.0 version. Said bug does not occurr when running nunit-console

Comment: TeamCity has its own NUnit runner, which produces really nice test summaries in the build web pages.  You should consider using that instead of NUnit itself.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but it hangs because of an NUnit bug. Did you read the last part of my question?

Comment: Ah, so when you say "NUnit Runner", you mean "TeamCity's NUnit Runner".  Never mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functionality was still there, found it by accident when looking at another build configuration. Importing an XML is now a "Build Feature", see:

[image]

Comment: Hi - So where is the nunit report suppose to show after you configure this?  I did the exact same thing but still can't see a nice (red/green) nunit report.

Comment: @Buzzer: In the Projects page, look for your project, it's in the same dynamic drop down menu where you access the build log. There, you'll find a link to the test report, and also a quick view of the test results.

Answer (score 10):

This could be done using `importdata` TeamCity message, this is really helpful when you are running NUnit tests manually executing nunit-console.exe from an MSBuild script, for instance using `NUnit MSBuild Community Task`, but keep in mind that TeamCity provides built in NUnit tests runner so you do not need this low level TeamCity scripting. Anyway you can import report in this way:

```xml
<Message 
         Text="##teamcity[importData type='nunit' path='...\TestResults.xml']" 
         Importance="High"/>
```

See [Importing XML Reports](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)

> If you prefer to run code coverage, code inspection, test tools or
>   duplicate finders directly from build script, not as a build runner,
>   you can use the importData service messages to import generated xml
>   reports into TeamCity.

Comment: Like I said in the last paragraph of my question (not an edit!), the NUnit runner hangs because of a bug in NUnit. Using the Command Line is just a temporary workaround until NUnit 2.6.0 is released. On the other hand, I didn't know about Team City messages. Gonna try this